# Wordpress: Removing posts in "The Loop" using filters

Tags: wordpress, filter, hook

After reading the Wordpress documentation, I realized you can remove posts from the index using filters inside "The Loop", e.g.:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- The following tests if the current post is in category 3. -->
<?php if (in_category('3')) continue; ?>

<!-- display normal post -->
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What I'm wondering is if there is a filter/hook to filter posts in `have_posts()` without modifying the template. So far, I found options to change the results, but not remove results form the result set.

Answer (score 4):

You can hook into 'pre_get_posts'.More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts. As the article describes:

> This hook is called after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run.

Using query_posts(), you can override the query variables and exclude any posts. The link has some decent examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to remove it from displaying but still have it 'there' incase you decide to show it later? Not really clear on what you want to do.

As one example, in the past I've used Query Posts to keep categories off of my homepage: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Exclude_Categories_From_Your_Home_Page

Comment: Got to agree with Adam here--use one of the category arguments (they can be found in that article Adam linked) with query_posts to filter your categories.